How can I optimize this flow for data table discoverability
Following is the workflow for a UI consisting of a data table and Accordion.

Search for an entity using cascading filters or search bar.
Based on the search results, the accordion 1 and 2 and the data table is loaded for that specific entity.
If user wants to see the previously saved data in data table, they need to click on accordion 1, then select the new cascading dropdown1 ( which houses the version of the data table ) and dropdown 2 ( which houses multiple entities if they are saved in the same data table). After selecting the values in new cascading dropdowns 1 and 2, a new view only data table is loaded.
If there exist multiple saved data tables for a single entity, user can use the CTA on the right that opens up a modal shows a consolidated view of multiple data tables related to that specific entity.

The stakeholders have said that it takes two many clicks to view the consolidated view of multiple data tables related to that specific entity.
And need your input to optimize the workflow.


Is the current design based on user research? Is there a problem with how it's designed and how people actually want and are going to use it? In other words, are the stakeholders right or wrong in your opinion?

@jazZRo
No, there is no user data available, its stakeholder's opinion and I have to optimize the workflow

@RightCheeseCoder Can you give a simple example of a use case? I find the generic description very hard to follow.

Right now it seems you have two choices:
(a) provide access to the consolidated view higher up in the UI hierarchy. I would suggest next to the search bar, according to the screenshots.
(b) If you do not need the input of the previous accordions to show the consolidated view provide it as a separate accordion in the main program.

It seems like the steps to view a consolidated view of multiple data tables involve multiple clicks and dropdown selections, which might be why stakeholders feel the process is a bit cumbersome.
1. Introduce a Quick Access Button
Right now, Users need to interact with several dropdowns and accordion menus just to view the consolidated data. This is slowing down their access to the most critical view.
You can introduce a “Quick Access” button right next to the search bar or within the accordion itself. This button can directly take the user to the consolidated view modal without requiring the intermediate steps of selecting from multiple dropdowns. For example, a button labeled "View All Data Versions" can instantly trigger the modal.
2. Pre-load Multiple Data Tables in the Background
The user has to open cascading dropdowns and select versions to load tables one at a time.
Pre-load all related data tables for the selected entity in the background. Once the user opens the modal, they can instantly see all the saved versions or entities at once. This reduces the need to select specific versions through dropdowns before viewing.
3. Modify Accordion 1
Accordion 1 is used to trigger new cascading dropdowns. This might feel like an extra step
Consider eliminating Accordion 1 entirely and instead surface the version selection dropdowns (new cascading dropdown 1 and dropdown 2) directly below the data table for faster access. Alternatively, you could automatically expand Accordion 1 after the user selects an entity, reducing the number of manual clicks.
4. Consolidate Dropdown Selections
There are two dropdowns (version and multiple entities) that the user has to interact with sequentially.
Combine the cascading dropdowns into a single dropdown with grouped options or multi-select. For example, you can have a single dropdown where each version has a nested list of saved entities. This cuts down the interaction steps from two selections to one.
5. Sticky Toolbar with Critical CTAs
The user must interact with the CTA inside the accordion to load the modal.
Have a sticky toolbar at the top of the screen, always visible when a search result is loaded, with a button for “Consolidated View” or “View Saved Data.” This keeps the essential functionality within immediate reach after performing a search and removes reliance on accordion navigation.
6. Refine Modal Usability
The modal currently shows all related data tables, but the process to get there is a bit tedious.
Ensure that the modal has a clear filter or search feature so users can quickly locate the data tables they’re interested in within the consolidated view. A table of contents or list of available versions at the top of the modal could further simplify navigation.
Revised Workflow:
Search for entity → System loads accordion + data table + version dropdowns.
Add a Quick Access Button for consolidated view next to the search or within accordion.
Reduce the number of dropdowns by combining version and entity selection.
Provide an immediate “Consolidated View” CTA in the toolbar.
